# Getting the drawing off the main thread

Tags: python, qt, python-multithreading, pyqtgraph

I remember seeing a post somewhere about being able to get the drawing in python off the main thread, but I can't seem to find it. My first attempt goes something like this but it doesn't work. It doesn't crash initially (it does eventually) but no drawing takes place. The idea is that `options` is a map of drawing functions each of which draws to a pyqtgraph, or a QTWidget, etc

```
from threading import *
from Queue import *

anObject1 = DrawingObject()
anObject2 = DrawingObject()
anObject3 = DrawingObject()


options = {
    0  : anObject1.drawing_func,
    1  : anObject2.drawing_func,
    2  : anObject3.drawing_func,
    3 : updateNon,
}

def do_work(item): #item is a tuple with the item at 0 is the index to which function
    #print str(item) + "\n"
    options[item[0]](item)

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

#This function is a callback from C++
def callback(s, tuple):
    #options[tuple[0]](tuple) #this works
    q.put(tuple) #this does not



num_worker_threads = 3
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()
```

Comment: did you mean this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/haiJsGhxTaQ/sTtMa195dHsJ

Comment: Thanks that is not it, but it sure looks like a good read!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is not possible to draw to a QWidget outside the main GUI thread. You can find many references to this in the Qt forums and documentation. However, it is possible to start a subprocess that draws into  an image in shared memory, and then display the image in the main process. This is the approach taken by `pyqtgraph/widgets/RemoteGraphicsView.py`; see `examples/RemoteSpeedTest.py` for an example of this.